# Blender 2.80 / MakeHuman MESS - MHX2 file importer won't work at all

Tags: add-on, makehuman

I'm not able to run the MHX2 importer (v 30) in Blender 2.80.

Yes, I know it's now on the **N** menu, instead of on the **T** menu, where it used to be up to Blender 2.79b.

But now the importer generates ERRORS on ERRORS while importing.

This is the long list of errors I get

[image]

Is it required to install the latest **UNSTABLE** version of MH (currently, 1.20 **ALPHA** 3)?!
I'd rather NOT: ALPHA (and also BETA) softwares actually give me **CREEPS**.

**EDIT**

Then, my question is:

Is there any known fix or workaround to be able to import MakeHuman 1.1.1 mhx2 files into Blender 2.80?

Otherwise, I'll have to **switch back to Blender 2.79b** - which would be **a major regression**, after waiting so much (not even to mention the upcoming 2.81 release, to come in the next months).

**UPDATE**

It seems that there are several versions of the exporter (MakeHuman side) and importer (Blender side)

I'm going to try the "forked" version (recommended): https://bitbucket.org/Aranuvir/mhx2-makehuman-exchange/downloads/

Then (in case the above didn't work) I'll try the "upstream" version: https://bitbucket.org/Diffeomorphic/mhx2-makehuman-exchange/downloads/

I'll let you know which (**if any**) worked for me, so you don't have to bang your head like I did.

**UPDATE 2**

None of the 2 worked **fully**.
But at least the first one was able to import the **poses ONLY** (not the **expressions** though, which was what I was actually going for!!!!)

Now, it seems I'm **DOOMED**!!
And I actually prefer **QUAKE**... ;)

Lucky me, I have a computer with **MakeHuman 1.1.1 and Blender 2.79b** installed.
And everything works perfectly.
So I can export the posed (i.e.: running away) and expressive (i.e.: terrorized) character from that machine to the actual production one.
And still be able to adjust the pose and expression to my taste.

Comment: So... what exactly is your question? The problem is that there currently is no stable version that is compatible with Blender 2.80. What are we supposed to to about that?

Comment: @metaphor_set Thank you for pointing that out. I edited my question.